# Click in Safari on a item in Favorites-Bar

Tags: safari, applescript, favorites

I'm trying to create a script that will click in Safari on a Favorites folder in the FAVORITES-BAR (just below the toolbar) to open it. Unfortunately without success. Does anyone know help?

Andy

Comment: As an idea, since the favourites bar is really just a group of bookmarks stored in _~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist_, would it be better if your script just allowed you to provide the name of a favourite link and it read from the `.plist` the URL to redirect you to ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that works for me on the latest version of Mac OS high Sierra.  To start with, if you don't already know which Favorite you would like to automate clicking, the code in this option supplies you with a list of your Favorites to choose from.  This is also assuming that your Favorites bar is already visible in Safari.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.1
    set yourFaves to name of buttons of group 1 of window 1 ¬
        of application process "Safari"
    delay 0.1
    set theURL to (choose from list yourFaves ¬
        with title ¬
        "FAVORITES BUTTONS" with prompt ¬
        "Which Favorite Would You Like To Visit?" OK button name ¬
        "GO THERE" cancel button name ¬
        "CANCEL" without empty selection allowed) as text
    click UI element theURL of group 1 of window 1 ¬
        of application process "Safari"
end tell
```

[image]

This solution has its limits though. This version will only retrieve the Favorites that are actually visible in the browser window.  I'm working on another solution which may get better results.  Will update this post shortly